# Scraping from java chart and drop down menu

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping

Im trying to scrape the data from 
https://www.snowyhydro.com.au/our-energy/water/storages/lake-levels-calculator/
Iam trying to scrape the lake levels for different years further by using the drop down menu by R.
Ar the moment Iam struggling as to where to start as I have searched various codes online and Iam unable to get a starting point as to how I can get yearly values for different lakes and Iam using R

Iam trying to use the selector gadget here but its not working as I reckon the charts are Java based

```r
library('rvest')

url <- 'https://www.snowyhydro.com.au/our-energy/water/storages/lake-levels-calculator/'
webpage <- read_html(url)
```

Iam looking for tabular results for daily storage levels for all he lakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a better url to use for requesting the data: `"https://www.snowyhydro.com.au/wp-content/themes/basic/get_dataxml.php`

The JSON response of the request isn't clearly interpreted as a table, but I think the functions here should accomplish that for you:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# This function is called from within the other to convert each day 
# to its own dataframe, creating extra columns for the year, month, and day
entry.to.row <- function(entry) {
  date = entry[["-date"]]
  entry.df = data.frame(
    matrix(unlist(entry$lake), nrow=length(entry$lake), byrow = T), 
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )
  colnames(entry.df) = c("LakeName", "Date","Measurement")
  entry.df$Date = date

  date.split = strsplit(date, split = "-")[[1]]
  entry.df$Year = date.split[1]
  entry.df$Month = date.split[2]
  entry.df$Day = date.split[3]
  entry.df
}

# Fetch the data for two years and convert them into two data.frames which 
# we will then merge into a single data.frame
fetch.data <- function(
  base.url = "https://www.snowyhydro.com.au/wp-content/themes/basic/get_dataxml.php",
  current,
  past
) {
  fetched = httr::POST(
    url = base.url, 
    body = list("year_current"=current, "year_pass"=past)
  )

  datJSON = fromJSON(content(fetched, as = "text"), simplifyVector = F)

  pastJSON = datJSON$year_pass$snowyhydro$level
  pastEntries = do.call("rbind", lapply(pastJSON, entry.to.row))

  currentJSON = datJSON$year_current$snowyhydro$level
  currentEntries = do.call("rbind", lapply(currentJSON, entry.to.row))

  rbind(pastEntries, currentEntries)
}

# Fetch the data for 2019 and 2018
dat = fetch.data(current=2019, past=2018)
```

```
> head(dat)
              LakeName       Date Measurement Year Month Day
1       Lake Eucumbene 2018-01-01       46.40 2018    01  01
2       Lake Jindabyne 2018-01-01       85.80 2018    01  01
3 Tantangara Reservoir 2018-01-01       42.94 2018    01  01
4       Lake Eucumbene 2018-01-02       46.41 2018    01  02
5       Lake Jindabyne 2018-01-02       85.72 2018    01  02
6 Tantangara Reservoir 2018-01-02       42.98 2018    01  02
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the post. I did try running the code but Iam getting the error about the fromJSON function. I tried using the library jasonlite but doesnt seem to be working. Can you let me know which package is fromJSON used from as iam geting error that it cannot find function content as weel.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would be helpful to know :) `fromJSON` is in the `jsonlite` package, and `content` is in the `httr` package.  I missed library calls when I copied the code, but I've added them in now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have changed the code a little to loop through the years and get all the data at once.

Comment: No worries, I have a reputation below 15 so my upvote won't show up. I have added the upvote and can added to your profile. I am so grateful for the help. also how can i accept the answer?

Comment: There should be a checkmark toward the top-left of the answer you can select (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Thanks, just checked it :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to capture the data from the link, Iam trying to do the same for another similar link but I am not sure how can I get the url for that? https://www.snowyhydro.com.au/our-energy/water/inflows/snow-depths-calculator/